# How to know a row's value before its inserted in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(date) FROM patients WHERE date= 2012/02/23
```

If that COUNT returns 10, there will be an alert that tells to the user that it cannot accept more visit.
How do i validate that? How can i know that? 
In php i just have to do this:

```
<?php

$QUERY = "SELECT COUNT(date) AS count_results FROM patients WHERE date= 2012/02/23";
$execute_query = $CONEXION ->prepare($query);
$execute_query->execute();
$results = execute_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(results['count_results ']==10)
{
echo "Cannot accept know visit.";
}else{
echo "Ok";
}
?>
```

But i have no idea of how to do that in ASP.NET C#. 
Help??

Comment: What .Net framework are you using?

Comment: @GabrielGM yes men....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform a check in the page_load event, if you are validating the logged in user.  Or if you need to validate depending on a user value that you are attempting to insert, use the button_click event for record being inserted.

```
SqlCommand cmdEvent = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(date) FROM patients WHERE date= '2012/02/23'", yourSqlConnection);
object myCount;
if (yourSqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed){ yourSqlConnection.Open(); }
myCount = cmdEvent.ExecuteScalar();
if (yourSqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open){ yourSqlConnection.Close(); }

if (myCount != null)
{
  if ((int)myCount >= 10)
  {
    // Logic here e.g myLabel.Text = "You have reached your maximum of 10 visits!";
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks men, ive looking for that so long :D