# How to know rows values sql server asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I posted this a few days ago [How to know a row's value before its inserted in gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041973/how-to-know-a-rows-value-before-its-inserted-in-gridview)
and i got this answer

```
SqlCommand cmdEvent = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(date) FROM patients WHERE date= '2012/02/23'", yourSqlConnection);
object myCount;
if (yourSqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed){ yourSqlConnection.Open(); }
myCount = cmdEvent.ExecuteScalar();
if (yourSqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open){ yourSqlConnection.Close(); }

if (myCount != null)
{
  if ((int)myCount >= 10)
  {
    // Logic here e.g myLabel.Text = "You have reached your maximum of 10 visits!";
    return;
  }
}
```

But now i dont need one row's value before its inserted, instead, i need to know the values of 2 rows and i have no idea of how to do it.
Im trying to make a login and i need the user's id to make the session unique but i need also to validate if that query returns true and i did it as follow:

```
comando = new SqlCommand("SELECT user_name FROM login WHERE user_name=@user AND pass=@pass", conexion);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", Upass);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
object check_coincidence = comando.ExecuteScalar();

if ((string)check_coincidence == user)
{
     Session["USER"] = check_coincidence;
     Response.Redirect("someURL")
}
```

But i do not know how to gat the user's ID to make the session unique, i mean, take that value as a new session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get more results from the query, you will have to use the SqlReader.

```
comando = new SqlCommand("SELECT user_name, user_id FROM login WHERE user_name=@user AND pass=@pass", conexion);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", Upass);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);

 SqlDataReader reader = commando.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var userName = Convert.ToString(reader["user_name"]);
            var userId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["user_id"]); 
        }
```

I would advice to follow some tutorials about this, it will help to understand the Sql-classes. Check this one for example: http://csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson03.aspx

Comment: THANX MEN!! I REALLY APRECIATE!